# How can I update a hook from one component and have it update another component as a result?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a hook with a state and use that as the common source for multiple components.

**What I've tried**:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

/**
 * Example of Hook that holds state, which should update other components when it changes
 */
const useExternalHookAsState = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('nothing yet');

  const updateMessage = (newMessage) => {
    console.log('message should be update to..', newMessage);
    setMessage(newMessage);
  }

  return [message, updateMessage];
};

/**
 * Example component for updating the state
 */
const MessageUpdater = () => 
{
  const [message, updateMessage] = useExternalHookAsState();

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={message} onChange={(e) => updateMessage(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};

/**
 * Expecting the message to be updated in here as well when the updateMessage is triggered, but that doens't happen
 */
const App = () => 
{
  const [message] = useExternalHookAsState();

  useEffect(()=> {
      console.log('effect on message tirggered');
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <div>
        <p>message is.. {message}</p>
        <MessageUpdater />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Expected behavior:** I was expecting that the new {message} will be updated in the App component but that just stays the same as 'nothing yet', and useEffect on the message doens't get triggered.

Am I using hooks in a wrong way? How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: it should be: `const [message, updateMessage] = useExternalHookAsState();` inside App.js as well

Comment: I don't that should be an issue. Also, I'm not using updateMessage in App.js so I see no reason to add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `message` inside `App` is not updated because you use `useExternalHookAsState` twice. The first time inside the `MessageHandler`, and the second time in `App` component. And they have **different** states. This way you only use `setMessage` in the child component of `MessageHandler`, which causes only that child component to be updated. And the `App` is not updated.

To solve this problem, raise the state and state management to the component in which you want to receive its updates. In your case, this is `App`. And then, through `props`, just pass the `value` and `setter` to the `MessageHandler` component.

The behavior you wanted to achieve is shown below:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const useExternalHookAsState = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('nothing yet');

  const updateMessage = (newMessage) => {
    console.log('message should be update to..', newMessage);
    setMessage(newMessage);
  }

  return [message, updateMessage];
};

const MessageUpdater = ({message, onUpdate}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={message} onChange={(e) => onUpdate(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {

  const [message, updateMessage] = useExternalHookAsState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect on message tirggered');
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>message is.. {message}</p>
      <MessageUpdater message={message} onUpdate={updateMessage}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks this does work! Now I understand what was wrong (useExternalHookAsState twice). I was hoping that there was a way to avoid using props since this is a simplified example of my implementation, and in the actual implementation MessageUpdater is 2 levels down from the App. Is there another way that I can store a global state in a component and update or get it from other components without using props?

Comment: If you will be passing props many levels down, it is not considered a good practice. Look at using [`context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instead. Or `state managers`, which allow you to take over all interaction with the state/data of the application. Such solutions include [redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux), [mobx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobx) and others.

Comment: Yes thanks this helps. Also the comments down here. I'm now looking into using either redux or context to accomplish this without passing down props

Answer (score 1):

Though the answer from xom9ikk is right (calling a hook twice will result in each hook having a different state, so one hook can't hold a global state as I've assumed), I have chosen to use the context approach as this doesn't require passing props and results in more clean code when working with a larger codebase.

The end example result that I've used is:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';

/**
 * Initializing Context
 */
const MessageContext = React.createContext();

/**
 * Creating provider with default state
 * - holds the state for the message used everywhere in the App
 * - takes children parameter because it needs to render the children of the context 
 * - updateMessage can be used from any child of provider and will update the global state 
 */
const MessageProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('nothing yet');

  const updateMessage = (newMessage) => {
    setMessage(newMessage);
  }

  return (
    <MessageContext.Provider value={[message, updateMessage]}>
      {children}
    </MessageContext.Provider>
  )
}

/**
 * Example component for updating the state
 */
const MessageUpdater = () => 
{
  const [message, updateMessage] = useContext(MessageContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>message in message updater is.. {message}</p>
      <input type="text" value={message} onChange={(e) => updateMessage(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
};

/**
 * Example of component that displays the message 
 * (all child components can use the message in the same way, without passing props)
 */
const App = () => 
{
  const [message] = useContext(MessageContext);

  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log('effect on message tirggered');
  }, [message]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Message in app is.. {message}</p>
      <MessageUpdater />
    </>
  );
};

/**
 * Wrapps the App with the provider that holds the global message state and update function
 */
const AppContext = () =>
{
  return (
    <MessageProvider>
      <App />
    </MessageProvider>
  )
}

export default AppContext;
```